# Return data from function with promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I need return data from this JS.
Where is console.log(...) i need return data from function to variale and I do not want use calback, i want use promise.

```
function retrieveData(){
    urllib.request(facebookURL, function retrieveDataFacebook(err, data, res) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }

        data = JSON.parse(data).shares;
        console.log("Facebook: " + data);
    });

    urllib.request(linkedInURL, function retrieveDataLinkedIn(err, data, res) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }

        data = JSON.parse(data).count;
        console.log("LinkedIn: " + data);
    });
}
```

Comment: what's wrong with a callback? even the code you've posted uses callbacks in the urllib.request.

Comment: Nothing, but I don't like callback hell.

Comment: You have two separate async requests that are running in parallel and each have some data.  Are you trying to return the data from both of them?

Comment: Yes, I want to return to the field and this field return from retrieveData.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a promise version using the [Bluebird promise library](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#all---promise) which helps turn async functions with callbacks into promise compatible functions:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
// make an promise version of urllib.request
var urllib.requestAsync = Promise.promisify(urllib.request);

function retrieveData(){
    var p1 = urllib.requestAsync(facebookURL).then(function(data) {
        return JSON.parse(data).count;
    });
    var p2 = urllib.requestAsync(linkedInURL).then(function(data) {
        return JSON.parse(data).count;
    });
    return Promise.all([p1, p2]);
}

retrieveData().spread(function(d1, d2) {
    // process your data here
}, function(err) {
    // some error here
});
```

You should also know that doing a `throw` from an async callback will not throw up to your higher level.  You won't be able to see the exception because at that point, the exception just goes into the node.js backend where the async response was created, not into your code.  Promises make this async error handling, much much simpler because they propagate exceptions or rejected promises back to your promise handlers.

Comment: @Data - what was your intended message by posting that link?  ES6 promises do not have the `.promisify()` method I'm using here.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass callback function from caller function. Because this function is working asynchronously so you do not know when it will get data to return . Code will look something like this.

```
function retrieveData(callback){
   urllib.request(facebookURL,callback);
}
```

and caller like this ...

```
 function getData(){
  retrieveData(function(err, data, res){
     // do something here 
  }) 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// create one function to capture any url request
function retrieveData(url, callback){

    urllib.request(url, function(err, data, res) {
        if (err) throw err;
        else callback(JSON.parse(data).shares);
    });
}

// callback
function processData(data){ 
    //doSomething 
}

// request url separately
retrieveData(facebookURL, processData);
retrieveData(linkedInURL, processData);
```